# How to check for duplicate CASE statement?

Tags: vb.net

I need the solution how to check for duplicate `CASE` statement in my code.

Example:

```
                Case "TEST1"
                    Dim ZR As New srv_test.frm1
                    ZR.ContinueInit()
                    ZR.MdiParent = Me
                    ZR.Show()
                Case "TEST2"
                    Dim BU As New srv_test.frm2
                    BU.ContinueInit()
                    BU.MdiParent = Me
                    BU.Show()
                Case "TEST1"
                    Dim ZR As New srv_test.frm1
                    ZR.ContinueInit()
                    ZR.MdiParent = Me
                    ZR.Show()
```

As you can see I have two duplicated `Case` statements in my code, what I need is to somehow check is there any duplicated `Case` statements since I have more then 500 cases in my code and can`t check it manualy.

Comment: `Case` can include expressions so in general you cannot check if there are duplicates at compile time. Even if you only have constants, what you should do instead is refactor your code to not include any `case`s at all.

Comment: Blah, so that means there is no solution to check is there duplicates? I can do it only manualy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> since I have more then 500 cases in my code and can`t check it manualy.

Real answer: find a better approach than such a huge statement.

Quick, short term fix: use text processing tools to select the applicable lines, extract the label and filter out unique values. This will identify the labels which you can then find in your usual editor. Using PowerShell it would be something like:

```
get-content *.vb | %{ if ($_ -cmatch 'Case\s+"(\w+)"') { New-Object PSObject -prop @{label=$matches[1]} } } | group label | ?{$_.Count -gt 1} | %{$_.Name}
```

Which:

- Reads the content of all the files `*.vb`
- For each line that matches the regex (this will need to be adjusted if your formatting is inconsistent), and pass on a custom object with property label.
- Group the results by that label.
- Remove all cases where the label only occurs once
- Return the group name (which is the label).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a different approach:
Define a Dictionary of string and Actions

```
Dim dic = new Dictionary(Of string, Action)()
dic.Add("TEST1", AddressOf RunTest1)
dic.Add("TEST2", AddressOf RunTest2)
dic.Add("TEST3", AddressOf RunTest3)
....
dic.Add("TEST1", AddressOf RunTestXXXX) 'the runtime will not allow this case'

Private Sub RunTest1
    Dim ZR As New srv_test.frm1
    ZR.ContinueInit()
    ZR.MdiParent = Me
    ZR.Show()
End Sub
Private Sub RunTest2
    Dim BU As New srv_test.frm2
    BU.ContinueInit()
    BU.MdiParent = Me
    BU.Show()
End Sub
Private Sub RunTest3
    Dim ZR As New srv_test.frm1
    ZR.ContinueInit()
    ZR.MdiParent = Me
    ZR.Show()
End Sub
Private Sub RunTestXXXX
.....
End Sub
```

Then, instead of calling an infinite Select Case you could add just one line

```
 currentTest = "TEST1"       
 dic(currentTest).Invoke()
```

of course, you need to all the function that you want to call and insert their addresses in the dictionary, but if you try to add a duplicate test case at runtime you will stop with an exception message.

Comment: I have to use CASE statement since I`m calling that case from SQL server to show up my menu items

Comment: Well, I don't understand your comment however I'm glad that you have found  a viable solution.